# Cross Domain Problems Using YQL

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to access this URL (outside of my domain) through ajax using jQuery
http://www.decolar.com/shop/flights/data/search/roundtrip/sao/orl/2013-09-11/2013-09-19/1/0/0/FARE/ASCENDING/NA/NA/NA/NA/NA

I tried to make this possible with YQL.

Here's my code:

```
        var url = 'http://www.decolar.com/shop/flights/data/search/roundtrip/sao/orl/2013-09-11/2013-09-19/1/0/0/FARE/ASCENDING/NA/NA/NA/NA/NA'; 

        var consultar = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
                    "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
                    encodeURIComponent(url)+
                    "%22&format=xml&callback=?";

        $.getJSON( consultar ,
            function(data){
                console.log(data);                    
                console.log(consultar);
                $('#content').html(data.results[0]);
            }
        );
```

I can access this Url with my browser, but using YQL, I have no data returning :(

Help me! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that XMLHttpRequest, which is the magic behind $.getJSON, does not support Cross Origin requests without a special handshake in the headers which some browsers support and others do not.  jQuery does support making cross domain requests, but you have to do it using script tag injection and something called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

See this thread for details: [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)